owl carousel not positioning rightly moving part of left side to right
owl carousel container not positioning centrally moving 10 px left side part to right or showing part of left on the right side 
<div class="carousel-section relative w-full">
    <div class="absolute left-0 right-0">
        <div class="text-carousel owl-carousel">
           <div class="flex justify-between">
               <div class="w-6/12">SPIDERMAN</div>
               <div class="w-6/12">SPIDERMAN</div>
           </div>
           <div class="flex justify-between">
               <div class="w-6/12">SPIDERMAN</div>
               <div class="w-6/12">SPIDERMAN</div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

